# C# Detecting the same string used in a List

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory

I am pulling a list of computer names from AD and then collecting the last user who logged in. For each computer i am pinging i would like to collect the last username that was logged in with computer name. If the list contains a username that is already in the list but, with a different computer name. I would like that username/computerhostname name added to a separate list box.

MY LIST would look like this:

1. username1 / COMPUTERHOSTNAME1
2. username2 / COMPUTERHOSTNAME2
3. username3 / COMPUTERHOSTNAME3
4. username1 / COMPUTERHOSTNAME4  <--- this would be added to a separate list to identify the username is moving to a new computer.

var same = MyList.GroupBy(n => n).Any(c => c.Count() > 1);
var groups = MyList.GroupBy(n => n).Select(t => new { count = t.Count(), key = t.Key });

```
                      MyList.Add(trimmed + " " + results1[i].Properties["cn"][0].ToString());

                      foreach (var group in groups)
                      {
                       //  Console.WriteLine(group.key + "     " + group.count);

                         if (group.count > 1)
                         {
                             duplicates.Add(group.key);
                         }

                      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `listBox2` is the place where you are adding the user details.

You can use below code to check whether it has dupticates or not.

```
listBox2.GroupBy(n => n).Any(c => c.Count() > 1);
```

You can play with `GroupBy`, `Distinct` and many other fucntions.

Comment: I edited my question. I am not sure if we are talking about same thing. I tried to use what you recommended but didn't work out. I might have been using it wrong but, in any case could you look at my edited question and help me figure out if I am close?>

Comment: Please update you question again. It is not at all readable, I am not able to figure out which variable is for what? You should not use variable names like `trimmed`, `result`, `duplicates` etc. First learn how to write it, technical things we can sort out later.

Comment: I apologize for the writing. I attempted to restate my question and also provide more code.